# Proof that we need to take advantage of trends and current events

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

[This question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/958/why-did-greece-go-through-over-russia-in-euro-2012) and [this question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/what-are-those-blue-stripes-or-patches-on-balotellis-back) about Euro-2012 has had over 9,000 views, without anybody having promoted it, proving that good content will get the visitors flowing in.

If there is a hot-topic in an event that the world is watching we should definitely be capitalising on it.

Don't forget: [it's okay to ask and answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) too.

This links in to the other meta discussions about the Olympics and how we can promote the site.

I welcome the discussion on this subject.

Comment: I hope this site blows up during the Olympics. I admit that I only watch swimming and track & field every four years ;)

Comment: Could be a good moment to give clear rules insight to not so common sport from experts (or at least people that know how it works).

Comment: I asked a question I asked which is an instance of a hot topic current event, [By what rule was the final play of the Packers/Seahawks game a touchdown?](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1618/by-what-rule-was-the-final-play-of-the-packers-seahawks-game-a-touchdown). I think it's appropriate to ask whether this is a good example of what we should aim for, or whether the question could be improved in any way.

Comment: I asked this question, which I really wanted to know: http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1998/why-is-boxing-day-a-match-day-in-the-english-premier-league and for some reason it also got substantially more views than questions of the same age.

Comment: @Bernhard Your question about Boxing Day *probably* received more views than other questions because you asked it on Boxing Day. Just an observation.

Answer (score -3):

I'm going to keep this short and sweet.

Stack Exchange is meant for people to have a Q&A about questions somebody faces. Not things that you ask because you want to take advantage of a hot topic. Where's my proof? [It's in this blog post.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/06/can-stack-exchange-capitalize-on-hot-trends/)

To finish off, let me quote Yannis Rizos's comment on the above blog post:

> Hm… I don’t think there’s a problem here, other than trying to make up questions. That’s a recipe for failure, Stack Exchange is supposed to be about “practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face” and not questions based on what happens to be hot this week. If your practical and actual problem happens to also be related to a “hot” topic, lucky you, but anything else is a bit fishy.

Comment: I'm sorry but I disagree.  I'm not suggesting we try to "make up questions".  Everybody in the pub was asking why Greece went through ahead of Russia when it happened.  It wasn't a made-up question.  It was a question **people were actually asking.**  I think, had that question not have been asked here already, it would have been perfectly acceptable for one of us to post it ourselves.

Comment: I'm with @Ste on this. Here's another example: http://sports.stackexchange.com/q/15/35 . I knew the answer when I posted it - it was during the beta, and the point was to post representative questions - but it comes up every time someone runs a sub-2:04 marathon.